# How to access a property of a component in React from another file

Tags: reactjs, properties, components

```
import Buttons from "./components/Buttons"


function Calculator() {

  function handleButtons(i) {
    return(
      <Buttons value={i} onClick={printNumber}/>
    )
  }

  function printNumber() {
    console.log("Hello");
  }


  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {handleButtons(1)}
        {handleButtons(2)}
        {handleButtons(3)}
      </div>
      <div>
        {handleButtons(4)}
        {handleButtons(5)}
        {handleButtons(6)}
      </div>
      <div>
        {handleButtons(7)}
        {handleButtons(8)}
        {handleButtons(9)}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Calculator
```

I'm trying to print out the number that corresponds to the button that is being clicked. But I dont know how to access the properties(value) of Button component from this file.

Here is the other file

```
function Buttons(props) {
    
    return (
        <button onClick={props.onClick}>{props.value}</button>
    )
}

export default Buttons
```

Im new to react btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code too,

```
import Buttons from "./components/Buttons"


function Calculator() {

  function printNumber(num) {
    console.log(num);
  }


  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Button value={1} onClick={() => printNumber(1)}/>
        <Button value={2} onClick={() => printNumber(2)}/>
        <Button value={3} onClick={() => printNumber(3)}/>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Calculator
```

Comment: Thank you! this solved my problem. But one more question. What if I didnt want to include the arrow inside the Button component but instead only '''onClick={printNumber(1)}''' is there other way it still can run as it is

Comment: if you will do that, the code won't function the way you want it to because when the interpreter will parse the code it'll execute the function while parsing rather than when you will click on it, that's why we always pass a reference which states that execute the function only on the click event.

Comment: onClick={() => printNumber(1)}, in this line we are passing the reference to the arrow function which further executes the printNumber() when the user clicks on the button

Comment: You have to dig a bit by yourself and don't worry you will get a clear picture of everything as to why they happen in a certain way